# How to set the input control of type datetime-local to the current time

Tags: javascript, angular

I am straggling to set the date and time of my input field of type `datetime-local` in Angular to the current time.

Below is the section of my template html file.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" *ngIf="isLoaded && !isAdmin">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-5">
            <label>Date</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" formControlName="scheduledDate" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have tried the suggestion given on stackblitz [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gk2fpf) but it gives me strange error `ERROR Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [NgControl]`

Answer (score 0):

according to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) the thing that you are looking for is a HTML property called `value`, the `ngModel` should work as well.

```html
<input type="datetime-local" [value]="today"/>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  today = new Date();
}
```

You may find the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f9khtm?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks. Somehow it does not work for me. The stackblitz example doesn't seem to be working either - it displays just the template for date time (dd/mm/yyyy --;-- --)

Comment: Maciej any suggestions? I am trying to desperately solve this problem.

Comment: hmm sorry, I don't know, it is odd tho :/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know angular but a vanilla js solution is

```html
 <input type="datetime-local" data-name="dateStart" id="dateTimeStart"
```

```js
const now = new Date();
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes()-now.getTimeZoneOffset());
document.getElementById('dateTimeStart').value = now.toISOString().slice(0, 16);
```

I guess this can be adapted for Angular !?